# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when I go to domain: Nginx, Daphne, Django, DigitalOcean

Tags: django, nginx, daphne

I'm running a Django Channels app on DigitalOcean, Ubuntu 16.04 using Daphne and Nginx.

Followed [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/9ah9ez/deploying_django_channels20_on_nginx/).

> Nginx will only be used as a proxy for your django application, your
>   django application will be running with daphne.
>   And you should have daphne running on 127.0.0.1:8001 (or change the
>   port to your likings).

I have enabled Let’s Encrypt SSL for my page and told all `http` requests to be redirected to `https`.

My page is showing the error

```
myapp.com redirected you too many times.
```

I'm running daphne on `127.0.0.1:8001`.

```
daphne -b 127.0.0.1 -p 8001 myapp.asgi:application
```

My nginx config file

```
server {
    server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;
    server_tokens off;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot  
}

server {
    if ($host = www.myapp.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = myapp.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

    root /home/me/myapp/src/myapp;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        root /home/me/myapp/src/myapp;
    }

    location /media/  {
        root /home/me/myapp/src/myapp;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @python_django;
    }

    location @python_django {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your configuration file has the main location blocks in the wrong server block. The configuration from your previous question looked correct except for line 2 which needed to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The first block of your configuration is not properly set. The `listen 443` line is supposed to be on the second block. Try to these configurations.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;
    server_tokens off;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot  

    root /home/me/myapp/src/myapp;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        root /home/me/myapp/src/myapp;
    }

    location /media/  {
        root /home/me/myapp/src/myapp;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @python_django;
    }

    location @python_django {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I changed my code and then got `directory index of "/home/me/myapp/src/myapp/" is forbidden` then changed `try_files $uri $uri/ @python_django;` to `try_files $uri / @python_django;` as another post suggested and am back to `err- too many redirects` and nothing in the nginx error log.